# Experience with dovecot mail server/roundcube web mail client

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, debian-lenny, roundcube

I'm currently building a web server with a mail server:

- Debian Lenny
- Apache 2.2
- PHP 5.3
- Dovecot
- Postfix

I am unsure of which mail client to use. I have my eye on roundcube since it looks cooler than squirrel mail.

- But is roundcube stable?
- What is your experience?
- Do you got any alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have extensive experience with squirrel mail but adopted round cube about a year ago.  I like it much, much more.  It's easier to set up and create extensions for.  I use it in the following environment:

- Ubuntu Server
- Apache2
- Php5
- Dovecot
- Postfix
- Mysql

I have it set up to work with postfix and mysql so that I don't need to create real users on my server. They are all virtual.  RoundCube let's my users easily choose which domain that they need to access.

My biggest peeve with RoundCube is that (at least the version I have install) it doesn't support updating passwords.  I have to use postfixadmin for that.

Comment: Most common user complaint here is that they cannot setup auto responder from Roundcube (never bothered to look extending RC to let it talk to the mailserver and setup responders, currently done with qmailadmin - there's vpopmail behind the scenes)

Answer (score 0):

Love roundcube! The only thing that's missing from it is PGP/GPG support.

It's stable, fast, works very well with dovecot, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I've also switched from Squirrel to RoundCube for my personal domain. From an admin point of view it's six of one and half dozen of the other. From a user point of view RoundCube is a whole lot nicer to use.

Answer (score 0):

To preface this - I'm a bit of a minimalist but I prefer Squirrelmail despite it being ugly, it scales well has some nice backend options; I've never had any problems with it. I've played around with RoundCube but it tends to be too buggy for me.

Theres Horde and a few more obscure webmail MTAs or you can always use something like Zimbra.

Answer (score 0):

Currently have a Debian:Apache,mysql,postfix,php,dovecot running virtual clients. For simplicity I use postfixadmin to add virtual domains and clients and currently using squirrelmail to provide webmail access though I do encourage the use of a desktop mail client (outlook, thunderbird, windows livemail, Any rfc based pop3/Imap/SMTP cient that supports our security settings). Latley our clients have been asking about a more friendly webmail client, so I am trying to have both squirrelmail and roundcube on the same server. So far it has worked nicely save for the lack of documantation on some plugins. A nice interface to enable/disable plugins with plugin description would be nice.